# Is the Canon Semi Hard Case EH19-L good for an entry-level body plus 18-135 lens?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, equipment-protection, camera-cases

On the [Canon site](https://store.canon-europe.com/store/canoncon/it_IT/DisplayProductDetailsPage/Semi_Hard_Case_EH19-L/productID.108246400), is not mentioned. Is this product good for a Canon 600D plus 18-135mm lens?

If the answer is no, which similar case do you suggest for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, at least for the Canon Italy:

> Buongiorno Sig.xxxx,
>   diciamo che questa volta gli americani hanno sbagliato .....
>   Per scrupolo , ieri prima di scrivere abbiamo verificato la custodia fisicamente ..e confermiamo che il modello EH 19L è utilizzabile SOLO con Corpo macchina + obiettivo 18-55.ed è compatibile con i modelli seguenti modelli EOS 600D, 550D, 500D, 450D, 1100D, 1000D
>
> Good morning Mr.xxxx, at this time the Americans are wrong.... To be sure, yesterday we have physically verify the case, and we confirm that the model EH19-L is compatible ONLY with body + lens 18-55 and is compatible with the following models: EOS 600D, 550D, 500D, 450D, 1100D, 1000D

The bags suggested me are 1EG, 10EG or 100EG.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it does fit the camera combination that you have according to the B&H Photo Video website - [here](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/547889-REG/Canon_2748B002_EH19_L_Semi_hard_Case.html). They state that the EH19-L is:

> Compatible with: Rebel T1i with EF-S 18-55 mm IS lens, a T2i with EF-S 18-55 mm IS or IS II lens, a T3 with 18-55 mm IS II lens, a T3i with 18-135 mm IS lens or 18-55 mm IS II lens, an XS with 18-55 mm IS lens or EF-S 18-55 mm IS lens refurbished, an XSi or XSi refurbished, an RFD RBL T1I or an RFD T1I

Also, the [Canon USA site](http://shop.usa.canon.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_10051_10051_172247_-1) does describe the following as compatible:

> -- EOS Rebel T3i 18-135mm IS Lens Kit

As a note, the Canon T3i is the US name for the Canon 600D.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know what T3i mean. Now I also checked the [US Canon store](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/slr_cameras/modelSNACompatibles.action?accessoryCid=0901e024801dba7b&accessoryModelName=SEMI+HARD+CASE+EH19-L). It seems that it's compatible. Maybe I hope.

Comment: Baduel: You are right, Canon uses different model names in the U.S. - little bit confusing. For example, I had and old Rebel GII which was the same as Eos 3000N, but the first one was U.S. version.

Comment: As a note: the Canon support Italy has called me saying that this case IS NOT compatible with the combination camera-lens described in my question. They suggest me a 1EG, 10EG or 100EG. Very strange!

Comment: @Baduel - I verified, and on the Canon USA website, it does list your camera and lens combination as compatible "EOS Rebel T3i 18-135mm IS Lens Kit". Very odd indeed that Canon ITaly would suggest non compatibility.

Comment: Canon USA Product description(Compatibility info in 2nd tab): http://shop.usa.canon.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_10051_10051_172247_-1

Comment: Yes, I've seen. For this reason it's strange...

Comment: All my effort, not even a vote :(

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I've previously accepted your answer because I had found the corresponding compatibility in the US store.

Comment: @Baduel — I think you should refrain from selecting an answer at all until it's determined which country's distributor is in error.

Comment: @mattdm They wrote me that they have tried physically to put the camera + 18-135 lens but without success. Therefore I think that the answer is no. I hope they are wrong =)

Comment: Well that sounds pretty definitive.